# Nested form in many to many relationship in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have a model Contact which has a many-to-many relationship with Company:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base   has_many :contactcompanies  
  has_many :companies, through: :contactcompanies
```

Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :contactcompanies  
  has_many :contacts, through: :contactcompanies
```

ContactCompany:

```
class ContactCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :contact
```

contacts_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new

  @all_companies = Company.all

  @contact_company = @contact.contactcompanies.build
end
```

contact create form where I want to have a multiple select for companies:

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= f.label :image_url %>
  <%= f.text_field :image_url %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= fields_for(@contact_company) do |cc| %>
    <%= cc.label "All Companies" %>
    <%= collection_select(:companies, :id, @all_companies, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-action">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                contacts_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>                
<% end %>
```

My issue is when I go to /contacts/new I get this error:
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Contactcompany

Any ideas? I'm searching for hours without success. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your class as "ContactCompany"

This implies:

```
has_many :contact_companies  
has_many :contacts, through: :contact_companies
```

Without the underscore, it is looking for a class named Contactcompany, which does not exist.